# I need Google Cloud Build "finaly step"

Tags: google-cloud-build, cloudbuild.yaml

The problem: Some steps create entities in K8b that must eventually be removed regardless of the success of any other steps in the build.

Here is an example of `cloudbuild.yaml`

```yaml
steps:  

  # TEST NAMESPACE
  #
  # some previous steps...
  # package jar
  # build container & etc.

  # Kubernetes RUN DB
  - name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/gke-deploy'
    id: deploy-db
    waitFor: ['-']
    args: ['apply',
           '--filename', './k8b/db/',
           '--location', 'somewhere',
           '--cluster', 'my-trololo-cluster']
  # Run something else in Kubernetes
  - name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/gke-deploy'
    id: deploy-other-things
    waitFor:
      - 'deploy-db'
    args: ['apply',
           '--filename', './k8b/other-things/',
           '--location', 'somewhere',
           '--cluster', 'my-trololo-cluster']

  # Test DB in pod
  - name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/gke-deploy'
    id: test-db
    waitFor:
      - 'deploy-other-things'
    entrypoint: 'bash'
    args: ['./scripts/test_db.sh']
    

  # Run REST-API
  - name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/gke-deploy'
    id: deploy-rest
    waitFor:
      - 'deploy-other-things'
    args: ['run',
           '--filename', './k8b/rest/',
           '--location', 'somewhere',
           '--cluster', 'my-trololo-cluster' ]
  # Test REST-API
  - name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/gke-deploy'
    id: test-REST-API
    waitFor:
      - 'deploy-rest'
      - 'test-db'
    entrypoint: 'bash'
    args: ['./scripts/test_rest_api.sh']

  # Cleanup steps
  - name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/gke-deploy'
    id: cleanup
    waitFor:
      - 'test-REST-API'
    entrypoint: 'kubectl'
    args: [ 'delete', '--filename', './k8b', '--recursive' ]
 
  # Delete PERSISTENT VOLUME
  - name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/gke-deploy'
    id: delete-persistent-volume
    waitFor:
      - 'test-REST-API'
    entrypoint: 'bash'
    args:
      - '-c'
      - |
          pvc_name=$(kubectl get pvc --selector=$sel -o jsonpath={.items..metadata.name})
          kubectl delete pvc ${pvc_name}
```

So, if any step before the “cleanup steps” fails, the deletion of entities in GKE will not occur.
And the next cloudbuild runs will not happen on a clean cluster.

I can't find any solution to this case in the docs.

And I think that at the moment I can solve this problem using bash scripts at every step, and if there is a crash, I need to:

- catch it in a bash script;
- give a command to clear the cluster inside the bash script;
- then exit the script with a non-zero code.
  And so in every step.

But this is not a very good solution in my opinion. Maybe there is some better solution?

Comment: I had exactly the same question and all I found from CloudBuild is that we should use the bash step for retries and conditional logic. More info [here](https://cloud.google.com/build/docs/configuring-builds/run-bash-scripts)

Comment: @Neara , unfortunately bash-scripts do not solve my problem.
I definitely need the final step in cloudbuild.